# How to define API Parameter as formData in Swagger UI

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I am working with Gradle and integrating Swagger and in my `build.gradle`, I have added below dependencies:

```
implementation('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.8.0')
implementation('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.8.0')
```

I have the below API in my controller class:

```
@RestController                                                                                                                                                
@RequestMapping("/v1/files")                                                                                               
                                 
public class FileController {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                               
  @PostMapping(produces = "application/json")                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  public ResponseEntity<UploadFileResponse> uploadFile(                       
      @ApiParam(value = "Metadata of file") @RequestParam Map<String, String> metadata,                                              
      @ApiParam(value = "File to upload", required = true) @RequestParam MultipartFile file) 
      throws IOException {                                  
        //business logic here
      }
```

In my Swagger-UI, I am seeing ***query for metadata param*** and ***formData for file param***.

I also wants to change metadata location also ***formData*** instead of ***query-param***. Can anyone suggest me how to do it?

[image]